# Angular material slider change event doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular2 `md-slider` in a component and I have a problem  with the change event:

- first I change the value using the slider for example to 20.
- next I change the value to 19 using a button and function in controller
- and again I change the value to 20 using slider. But it doesn't fire the change event.

Comment: Can you add some code sample?

Comment: Here is a plunker with the exact same problem https://plnkr.co/edit/so7fsq9u7yev0y2xlMXx?p=preview

Comment: In this plunker is the same problem but there isn't solution :(

Comment: I think this is an internal issue with the MdSlider component caused by the fact that it only emits a `change` event if the newly value is different to the last _emitted_ value (as opposed to the current value). You can see this in the code [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/slider/slider.ts#L585).

Comment: I've gone ahead and [added an issue to Github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6195) so track responses/progress over there.

Comment: Will using `input` instead of `change` be a solution for you, `(input)="onChange($event)`? Check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1yiehVyBYio3wynHx9Ka?p=preview)

Comment: No, this isn't solution for me. I have already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit the value yourself.

When you change the slider via a method, also emit the change:

```
this.slider.value = 10;
this.slider.change.emit({ source: this.slider, value: this.slider.value });
```

I believe they fixed this, but this helps if you want the event emitted when the value is changed via a method as well.